# Gimp 2.10 will not start due to undefined symbol: gegl_operation_get_source_space

Tags: gimp

After upgrade to 18.10 Gimp 2.10 will not start. I reinstalled it but no luck.

Found this error in logs:

gimp-2.10: symbol lookup error: gimp-2.10: undefined symbol: gegl_operation_get_source_space

What could be wrong

Comment: Is that the Gimp from the Ubuntu repos or the Gimp from the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp)?

Comment: From the Software Center so I guess Ubuntu repos, right? Used PPA before in 18.04 for previous version of Gimp

Comment: I don't think I have gegl installed. How do I check that and install it on Ubuntu 18.10?

Comment: Update: I have libgegl-0.4-0

Answer (score 16):

It was a problem with a local version of libgegl. Uninstalled Gimp and removed libgegl by 'sudo apt-get remove libgegl-0.4-0:amd64'. Reinstalled Gimp via Software Center, got a new libgegl from that and now it's working.

Comment: worked for me too, thanks. Others may find, as I did, that removing gimp (sudo apt remove gimp) then prompts an autoremove (sudo apt autoremove) which includes libgegl and others.

Comment: Also you need to remove libgegl-common if it's installed on your system. You can find all the gegl packages here: `apt search gegl`

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to remove Gimp, remove `gegl` libraries and re-install Gimp. I did:

```bsh
sudo apt remove gimp
sudo apt remove *gegl* # to remove all gegl libraries. Then,
sudo apt install gimp # to reinstall Gimp. The gegl libraries are reinstalled here too.
```

Then it worked.